# How cells are reused in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, addsubview

I think that I am missing something in a way that cells are reused in my UITableView.

I have ViewController with TableView and custom cells with their own class and identifier. In cellForRowAt method I use

```
let cell: MyCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.objectForCell = myObject
```

And it works as it should, I got TableView with cells.
I also have object that i pass to my cell. And inside cell I have this code

```
var objectForCell : ObjectClass? {
    didSet {
        if let object = objectForCell {
            someLabel.text = object.title
            ....
```

That also works fine. 
But what if I want to add some subviews to cells? For example let it be each 3rd cell. When TableView is presented I see my subview in each 3rd cell as I expect but why I got this subview in every cell when I start to scroll in different directions?

```
var objectForCell : ObjectClass? {
    didSet {
        if let object = objectForCell {
            someLabel.text = object.title
            if object.id % 3 == 0 {
               self.addSubview(......)
            }
```

Comment: Just pass the view to the cell and in the cell class add the view in the `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: could you please describe a little more what is going on right now and why awakeFromNib would be better?

Comment: Are you aiming to create a new view and add it as a subview into the cell? or is it just an existed view and you want to show/hide it based on what's the cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cellForRowAt` will return an existing cell object if there is one that is no more used by the table view. If that cell was a third one when it was presented, it has that new `subview` added. So to make it work as you expect, you would have to remove that subview in `prepareForReuse` which is called when that cell is being removed from view hierarchy and enqueued in the queue of reusable cells. That way when you call `dequeueReusableCell`, you will get a cell without the new subview.

**However**, in general, you do **not** want to add/remove subviews in `cellForRowAt` (unless there is no other option). Rather, if it is only a single specific view that you want to show in every third cell, add it in `initializer` and hide/unhide it in `cellForRowAt` (in your case, in `objectForCell`).

So declare a property:

```
let specialSubview = UIView()
```

Add it in `init` (or, if you use `nib`, then in `awakeFromNib`) and position it:

```
self.addSubview(specialSubview)
// autolayout constraints, configuring, etc.
```

And then in `objectForCell`:

```
var objectForCell : ObjectClass? {
    didSet {
        if let object = objectForCell {
            someLabel.text = object.title
            if object.id % 3 == 0 {
                specialSubview.isHidden = false
            } else {
                specialSubview.isHidden = true
            }
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any way that awakeFromNib can help?

Comment: @moonvader As I explained in the first paragraph - reusing means that you will again get a cell that you previously configured. If in configuring you are adding subviews, then you have to remove them before again using it, otherwise they will stay there. Therefore what you want is to configure subviews just once - that can be done in `initializer` or in `awakeFromNib`, since those are called once when the object is created. Then in `objectForCell` you can simply show/hide the proper views.

Comment: @moonvader  But it depends on how are you creating your cells - I do everything programmatically, thus in my case `awakeFromNib` is not used at all. If you are using nibs, then you should create those views in `awakeFromNib`.